# How to install a single Perl Crypt::OpenSSL::AES for use by different linux environments

Tags: linux, perl, openssl, cpan

I have a sticky problem that I am not quite sure how to solve. The situation is as follows:

- We have a common 32bit perl 5.10.0
- It is used by both 32bit and 64bit linux machines

Now the problem is that I need to install Crypt::OpenSSL::AES module for the Perl, however since it builds a shared library a lot of problems appear:

- If built on 64bit machines the module is not usable with "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64" error for the generated AES.so
- If built on a 32bit machine the module is not usable on the 64bit with undefined symbol: AES_encrypt

The problem I'm guessing is that the different machines have different versions of OpenSSL installed and they are not compatible with each other.

My question is given that I cannot change any of the machine configurations, what should I do to get the AES module working on all the machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with a combination of [staticperl](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/App-Staticperl-1.43/bin/staticperl) and building statically linked Crypt::OpenSSL::AES so that I have a single perl executable that is fully statically linked.

Given that I am not able to modify the environment, this is the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Perl's default configuration very intentionally puts platform-specific things in a separate directory; you appear to have broken that model.  Consider restoring it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? You mean the correct approach is to have multiple perl installations?

Comment: For different architectures, yes.  Maybe you can find a way around this problem, but there will be another down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you built your perl on a 32 bit machine, so during the build process, Configure didn't include any of the 'make this 32 bit' compiler switches. If you build on a 64 bit machine now, the build process will use exactly the same switches, so you get a 64 bit binary that cant't be loaded from 32 bit perl - not even on the 64 bit machines, beacuse the 32 bit perl binary you're running there can't load a 64 bit shared library either.

You might try building your shared perl on a 64 bit machine, explicitly stating you want a 32 bit perl. There should be some configure parameters for this. That way, you have a perl that sets the "use 32 bit" compiler flag when building modules. Then, you can use that version of perl on each of the machines to build the module. The modules won't be identical, but each of them will run on its bit size, and your software distribution process could pull the correct module when distributing to a specific machine.

However, the real problem is somewhat behind. I assume someone in your company at some point said "We don't want to be dependent on what the distributions provide, let's build our own perl that we can copy everywhere". This sounds like a good idea, but it is NOT. Different Linux versions use different versions of shared libraries, default directories for configuration files, default path variables etc. The configure process takes care of that and creates a perl binary for exactly your machine. If you copy this to a different machine, it might not find symbols in other versions of shared libraries. It might try to read lib from directories that don't exist there. It might not include a workaround for some bug that was corrected on the machine where you built it, but need the workaround on the older system you copied it to. Or, it might provide a workaround for something that has long been fixed on the newer system, thus wasting CPU time.

So, essentially, creating one perl to copy everywhere will ONLY work well if you build a static perl that includes everything and doesn't need any shared libraries. The standard, shared-library-using perl you compile on one machine, does NOT meet the "behaves the same everywhere i copy it to" request you probably had, because it depends way too much on stuff "around" it.